# Unable to control checkbox checked status - jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't get this onClick event to control the checked status of the checkbox.. any thoughts?

```
        init: function () {
            $('.billing input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                iKeyless.page.toggleShippingForm($(e.currentTarget));
            });
        },
        toggleShippingForm: function (el) {
            if (el.attr('checked')) {
                $('.shipping').parents('.yui-u').addClass('hide');
                el.attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                $('.shipping').parents('.yui-u').removeClass('hide');
                el.attr('checked', true);
            }
        }
```

It loads with the checkbox checked and it stays checked regardless of what I do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be `this` passed in to refer to the `<input>` element...though you don't need a jQuery object, here's a working version:

```
init: function () {
    $('.billing input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        iKeyless.page.toggleShippingForm($(this));
    });
},
toggleShippingForm: function (el) {
    if (el.attr('checked')) {
        $('.shipping').parents('.yui-u').addClass('hide');
        el.attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('.shipping').parents('.yui-u').removeClass('hide');
        el.attr('checked', true);
    }
}
```

But since [`.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) is a DOM property, you can just do this (without converting to a jQuery object):

```
init: function () {
    $('.billing input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        iKeyless.page.toggleShippingForm(this);
    });
},
toggleShippingForm: function (el) {
    $('.shipping').parents('.yui-u').toggleClass('hide', el.checked);
}
```

The element's changing it's `.checked` status already...just use it in the `change` event.  If needed, change the `.toggleClass('hide', el.checked)` to `.toggleClass('hide', !el.checked)`, depending on which way it should be visible.